# MTKView always render the background color to red

Tags: swift, macos, metal, metalkit

I want to use MTKView on Mac app. After init the MTKView, it appears red instead of the expected clear color on My laptop is MacBook Pro of macOS Catalina 10.15.2, and it render black background on a iMac of macOS Mojave 10.14.6

I try to exchange the metalView's pixelFormat (MTLPixelFormat.bgra8Unorm) to  MTLPixelFormat.rgba16Float or other. the background color is incorrect too.

The `MTLTexture` create function is `MTLTextureDescriptor.texture2DDescriptor(pixelFormat:metalView.colorPixelFormat, width: Int(metalView.frame.size.width), height: Int(metalView.frame.size.height), mipmapped: false)`

It could be a problem with the `.metal` file, but I don't understand it

I have post the project to Github. [here](https://github.com/joguo/MaliangMTK/tree/master/MTKViewRed)

```
import Cocoa
import MetalKit
import simd

struct Vertex {
    var position: vector_float4
    var textCoord: vector_float2

    init(position: CGPoint, textCoord: CGPoint) {
        self.position = [Float(position.x), Float(position.y), 0 ,1]
        self.textCoord = [Float(textCoord.x), Float(textCoord.y)]
    }
}

class Matrix {

    private(set) var m: [Float]

    static var identity = Matrix()

    private init() {
        m = [1, 0, 0, 0,
             0, 1, 0, 0,
             0, 0, 1, 0,
             0, 0, 0, 1
        ]
    }

    @discardableResult
    func translation(x: Float, y: Float, z: Float) -> Matrix {
        m[12] = x
        m[13] = y
        m[14] = z
        return self
    }

    @discardableResult
    func scaling(x: Float, y: Float, z: Float)  -> Matrix  {
        m[0] = x
        m[5] = y
        m[10] = z
        return self
    }
}

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, MTKViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!

    @IBOutlet weak var metalView: MTKView!

    private var commandQueue: MTLCommandQueue?

    private var pipelineState: MTLRenderPipelineState!
    private var render_target_vertex: MTLBuffer!
    private var render_target_uniform: MTLBuffer!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application

        metalView.device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
        metalView.delegate = self

        commandQueue = metalView.device?.makeCommandQueue()

        setupTargetUniforms()

        do {
            try setupPiplineState()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Metal initialize failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    private func setupTargetUniforms() {
        let size = metalView.frame.size
        let w = size.width, h = size.height
        let vertices = [
            Vertex(position: CGPoint(x: 0 , y: 0), textCoord: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)),
            Vertex(position: CGPoint(x: w , y: 0), textCoord: CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)),
            Vertex(position: CGPoint(x: 0 , y: h), textCoord: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)),
            Vertex(position: CGPoint(x: w , y: h), textCoord: CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)),
        ]
        render_target_vertex = metalView.device?.makeBuffer(bytes: vertices, length: MemoryLayout<Vertex>.stride * vertices.count, options: .cpuCacheModeWriteCombined)

        let metrix = Matrix.identity
        metrix.scaling(x: 2 / Float(size.width), y: -2 / Float(size.height), z: 1)
        metrix.translation(x: -1, y: 1, z: 0)
        render_target_uniform = metalView.device?.makeBuffer(bytes: metrix.m, length: MemoryLayout<Float>.size * 16, options: [])
    }

    private func setupPiplineState() throws {

        let library = try metalView.device?.makeDefaultLibrary(bundle: Bundle.main)
        let vertex_func = library?.makeFunction(name: "vertex_render_target")
        let fragment_func = library?.makeFunction(name: "fragment_render_target")
        let rpd = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
        rpd.vertexFunction = vertex_func
        rpd.fragmentFunction = fragment_func
        rpd.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = metalView.colorPixelFormat
        //        rpd.colorAttachments[0].isBlendingEnabled = true
        //        rpd.colorAttachments[0].alphaBlendOperation = .add
        //        rpd.colorAttachments[0].rgbBlendOperation = .add
        //        rpd.colorAttachments[0].sourceRGBBlendFactor = .sourceAlpha
        //        rpd.colorAttachments[0].sourceAlphaBlendFactor = .one
        //        rpd.colorAttachments[0].destinationRGBBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
        //        rpd.colorAttachments[0].destinationAlphaBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
        pipelineState = try metalView.device?.makeRenderPipelineState(descriptor: rpd)
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }

    func mtkView(_ view: MTKView, drawableSizeWillChange size: CGSize) {


    }

    func draw(in view: MTKView) {
        let renderPassDescriptor = MTLRenderPassDescriptor()
        let attachment = renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0]
        attachment?.clearColor = metalView.clearColor
        attachment?.texture = metalView.currentDrawable?.texture
        attachment?.loadAction = .clear
        attachment?.storeAction = .store

        let commandBuffer = commandQueue?.makeCommandBuffer()

        let commandEncoder = commandBuffer?.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: renderPassDescriptor)

        commandEncoder?.setRenderPipelineState(pipelineState)

        commandEncoder?.setVertexBuffer(render_target_vertex, offset: 0, index: 0)
        commandEncoder?.setVertexBuffer(render_target_uniform, offset: 0, index: 1)

        let textureDescriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor.texture2DDescriptor(pixelFormat: metalView.colorPixelFormat,
                                                                         width: Int(metalView.frame.size.width),
                                                                         height: Int(metalView.frame.size.height),
                                                                         mipmapped: false)
        textureDescriptor.usage = [.renderTarget, .shaderRead]
        let texture = metalView.device?.makeTexture(descriptor: textureDescriptor)
        commandEncoder?.setFragmentTexture(texture, index: 0)
        commandEncoder?.drawPrimitives(type: .triangleStrip, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: 4)

        commandEncoder?.endEncoding()
        if let drawable = metalView.currentDrawable {
            commandBuffer?.present(drawable)
        }
        commandBuffer?.commit()
    }
}
```

Could someone help me find the problem？

[image: this is the window always like]

Answer (score 6):

You're sampling from an uninitialized texture.

In your `MetalView`'s `draw` method, you bind the texture from the `screenTarget` variable, which has never been rendered to.

When a Metal texture is created, its contents are undefined. They might be red, black, random noise, or anything else.

Comment: In the same project, the other target named `MTKViewRed`, i remove all the additional code. could you help me fix this problem?

Comment: I honestly don't know what else to say. You're creating a texture, whose contents are **undefined**, then immediately sampling from it. The contents of the resulting image are therefore **undefined**, exactly as described in the answer. Perhaps you can tell us more about your expected result, because everything I'm seeing is consistent with my expectations.